# I have two data frames if one column value matches second df column values filter the onmatch column rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames here: df1 is here

```
id name
11 abc
12 cdf
13 mmm
14 hhh
```

df2 is here:

```
id status
11 1
12 1
13 0
```

What I need is `df1` id matches `df2` id then status 0 I have filter the complete row from `df1` like below

```
id name
11 abc
12 cdf
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "What i need is […]" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join them by id, and then filter by status value and dropping this last colum

```
     val joined = df1.join(df2, "id")
                     .filter($"status" !== 0)
                     .drop("status")
```

Line by line:

join => join both dataFrames by `id`, the result will have both `status` and name `columns` (besides `id column` obviously)
filter => keep only the rows that match the predicate. In this case the ones with `status` other than 0
drop => drop the `status` column since it is not required in the final output

Output is:

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
| 12| cdf|
| 11| abc|
+---+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..its working but the problem is in real time from df2 we may have more no of columns, i have to drop all of those columns in one go could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to `filter` the *rows* with `0` value in `status` column in `df2` and `select` only `id` column to be *inner joined* with `df1`. *This is better performance-wise than to filter after you join.*

```
val tempDF2 = df2.filter($"status" =!= "0").select("id")

df1.join(tempDF2, Seq("id")).show(false)
```

you should have output as

```
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|11 |abc |
|12 |cdf |
+---+----+
```